# Can't able to edit NewForm.aspx through browser

Tags: list

I created an empty list in prod environment using List Template(.stp) from development environment.
But I am not able to edit any of the list forms(NewForm.aspx, EditForm.aspx, DispForm.aspx) where I have to add a script editor webpart.
Same problem is observed in any newly created list custom list.
The same thing I able to do in my Dev Environment.
Is there any feature that I have activate ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this URL:

`(your list path)/NewForm.aspx?toolpaneview=2`

Comment: Thanks. but I resolved it earlier by adding the site in Compatibility view Settings of my IE browser. Later I tried your way and it also worked perfectly.